# Confused about size of the universe in the past

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, galaxies

From Wikipedia, I got that the photons of the cosmic microwave background radiation originated when the spherical volume of space which will become the observable universe was 42 million light-years in radius. But in the sky the universe at that time looks like a few billion years in circumference. The more in the past I look the farther away it is, and so the larger the circumference looks like. Or is this an optical illusion?
But if it is an illusion, should not galaxies in the past look larger in angular size?

Comment: Yes, beyond a certain distance galaxies increase in angular size the further away they are as angualr size only depends on the distance when lthe light was emitted.

Comment: Distant galaxies do look larger in angular size https://m.xkcd.com/2622/

Comment: See "Angular Diameter Turnover Point": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter_distance#Angular_diameter_turnover_point

Comment: Thanks to all commenters, I though my reasoning was completely wrong.

Comment: As maybe an aid to memory & maybe to score a win in some arguments you may begin getting, there's a diagram of how it happens (like John Davis said) in Figure 1 of the paper at https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/astro-ph/0402278/ , although you have to take the expansion of the Hubble Sphere  (as well as the fact that spatial expansion is not limited, like the relative motion of objects is, to the speed of light) into account, in order to see how the light of the most distant galaxies begins to approach us.